# Active Directory User Name in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs

Please pardon if my question sounds weird.

In ASP.NET project, we can get the active directory user name in code behind using Context.User.Identity.Name.

How can I get the AD user name in an Angular page?

Any pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: This feels way too broad to give a proper answer in it's current form;  You generally would get this data from the server to the client in the same manner that any other data gets sent.

Comment: I am not sure what extra info you require? Its a simple pure angular page where I would like to show the Active User Id. What will it take to show it. Please suggest a tutorial if if you feel its too broad?

Comment: umm, no.  requests for tutorials are absolutely off topic here.  There are multiple ways to pass data between your server and your client, and this value is no different from any other data that you would pass.  You haven't shown anything to explain how your project is set up, if you are using REST, WebAPI, Razor, etc., so it's not really obvious why you are having trouble passing this value but not other data.

Answer (score -1):

Short story you can't get the AD account using pure angular. That's because angular only exists on the client machine and your browser won't know what active directory will be out of the box.  As a result you'll need to pass the AD account as part of the ViewModel (Model, or ViewBag or ViewDictionary for MVC), or a web control for traditional ASPX. You can than use an on load function (or a scope init) to populate your application, with data that is populated into the HTML.

Comment: Maybe some comments on why this is downvoted would be useful? AFAIK, JS isn't aware of AD, right?

Comment: It's Angular JS, client side render, not server side content render, that's why the down vote. ViewBag, ASPX and etc has nothing to do with Angular JS. Also, there's no need of those to get any AD info using ASP.NET